# Post comment with facebook like button doesn't work

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-comments, xfbml

Im tryng to use the XFBML implementation of the Like Button, as it is described in the [facebook social plugin page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

The like button appears and works fine (it asks for a confirm action, but it works ok).

When i press the like button, a new dialog comment box popups that lets me add some comment to appear to my wall. However, when i press the "post to facebook" button, nothing happens and the popup dialog remains there. Finally, the comment doesn't appear to my facebook wall.

Any help??

Comment: Are you testing on a domain that is publicly reachable?  Most FB/Google+/etc. pages don't function correctly unless you 1) have the appropriate open graph tags in your page head and 2) your page is reachable on the public internet - meaning QA/localhost won't work.